# Die if visitor's browser is Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, web

Is it possible to display a message in a popup window that contains only one button for the visitor to click and close my website? I need this only for IE visitors.

EDIT: I found what to make use of, until I have the time to optimize the CSS for IE.

```
<!--[if IE]>
  <style>
    body { display: none; background: url('images/notice.jpg') top left no-repeat; }
  </style>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: Why would you want to ban IE users from your website ? If you really don't want them to be on IE I would strongly recommend showing a message asking them to download another browser, but the doorslam you're proposing is just poor UX

Comment: I won't do it permanently. I just dont have time to optimize my website's CSS for IE right now.

Comment: @ArgGeo If you write standards compliant code, and use best-practices like feature-detection and progressive-enhancement, IE will work for the vast majority of your stuff. IE9 and 10 will likely work 100%. Write rubbish, and IE will break ;)

Comment: You might try running your site through http://modern.ie and see what that says. If the test runner doesn't help you can get a few VMs to test your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: Not really.

Detailed answer: For detecting the browser used by the visitor, you need some information like the User Agent header. As this information is supplied by the user, you cannot rely on it, the user might have sent you any User Agent header.

Another way to detect the browser used by the visitor is performing a feature check, as some browsers implement additional stuff. The Internet Explorer has a `document.all` field accessible by JavaScript (at least the older versions have). But there might be other browsers out there, which have that field, too. Therefore, the presence of that field does not necessarily mean the browser is the Internet Explorer.

Comment: I think the OP should detail what exactly he's trying to achieve, drop legacy version support, check if it supports a new HTML5/CSS3 feature etc. There are different ways to achieve these things. And as you pointed out browser sniffing is not a good idea either

Comment: Well, the problem is that I dont have that much time to optimize my website for IE and I want to prevent visits until I fix it. It's a styling issue.

Comment: If automatically closing the website is impossible... is it possible to empty the content of the website as an alternative way?

Comment: @ArgGeo - what kind of styling issues do you have? Could it be as simple as a missing `<!DOCTYPE>` causing IE to go into quirks mode?

Comment: @Spudley I see extra paddings-margins, no inset shadows etc. I thought of using CSS PIE but I dont believe thats a "clean" practice.

Comment: @ArgGeo - if you're seeing extra margins, there's a very good chance it's quirks mode. That's easy to fix with a valid doctype.

Comment: @ArgGeo `<!DOCTYPE html>` is all that is needed in most situations. If that doesn't work, it's likely you wrote broken code.

Comment: @JonathanSampson My code is fine, I checked it three times. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Please please *please* do not do this.

Sure, old versions of IE were pretty rubbish, but IE9 and IE10 are decent browsers; IE10 in particular is right up there with the rest in terms of features and standards compatibility. Blocking it just because it's IE is really not the answer.

And IE11 is being developed. It's fair to guess that it'll be even better.

If you have specific features of your site that don't work in old IE versions, then use a feature detection script (eg Modernizr) to work out whether the user's browser doesn't support the features you need. *Then* maybe you have a case for popping up a message telling the user that they need to upgrade. But don't do it just based on the name of the browser.

If you've got styling issues, there are sometimes very simple solutions. Have you got a valid `<!DOCTYPE>` on your page? Not having one will cause styling issues in IE because it'll go into quirks mode, but it's dead simple to fix. Beyond that, modern versions of IE shouldn't have much in the way of styling issues; certainly not enough to warrant blocking the browser entirely. Older IE versions may do, but people still using IE6 or IE7 are used to seeing sites that don't look right; they're not going to be fazed by issues with your site, so blocking them doesn't really seem worth the trouble.

Comment: There is no future for IE Spudley. Every time bugs, everytime the styling is messed up etc... + As far as I know, according to browser statistics, IE user percentage is about 13 and every month is going lower... IE deserves to die and in my opinion this will happen soon. Why would someone use IE instead of Chrome or Mozilla?

Comment: Spudley: Quote Douglas Crockford: `IE9 must die!` ;) @ ArgGeo There are several reason to use IE and I doubt 1) you are the person to judge or foresee the future of IE 2) Microsoft will let that happen 3) Mozilla or Chrome are far in front e.g. in terms of security.

Comment: @Christoph I thought I was free to express my opinion as long as I dont live in North Korea...

Comment: That's not the point, I'm not a big fan of IE either, far from it, but what you're proposing is just bad practice. You simply cannot turn people away from your website just because they're using a specific browser